# Unexpected flexipage behaviour when created 2nd gen package

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, flexipages, issue, relatedrecord

I've meet the unexpected problem with flexipage when create 2nd gen package.

I've received an error looks like

> (SObject_Record_Page) Component [console:relatedRecord] attribute [lookupFieldName]: Cannot accept value [%s]  for lookup field value for related record component SObject.Field__c
> SObject_Record_Page: Component [console:relatedRecord] attribute [lookupFieldName]: Cannot accept value [%s]  for lookup field value for related record component SObject.Field__c

Part of flexipage is below

```
<itemInstances>
    <componentInstance>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>createQuickActionName</name>
            <value>NewAccount</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>lookupFieldName</name>
            <value>SObject.Field__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>titleFieldName</name>
            <value>SObject Information</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>updateQuickActionName</name>
            <value>Account.Info</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>console:relatedRecord</componentName>
        <identifier>console_relatedRecord</identifier>
    </componentInstance>
</itemInstances>
```

The only one I've found were  https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAweVAAS/managed-package-containing-lightning-record-page-related-record-component-will-fail-to-install-due-to-cannot-accept-value-s-for-lookup-field-val

Does this issue have solution or I have to use workaround from linked article?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked with Internal team on this bug(W-7968185) and currently we do not have any ETA about this fix. However fix would be rolled out in coming releases.

For now please use workaround mentioned in article and click on report button to get status updates on this bug.

> Create and upload a new package after removing the "Related Record" component from the Lightning Record Page.
>
> Insert the "Related Record" component on the subscriber org after the
> package is installed.